# how to extract the numbers in txt file in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file like this:

```
ASP62-Main-N     LYS59-Main-O    100.00%
THR64-Side-OG1   VAL60-Main-O    100.00%
ALA66-Main-N     LEU61-Main-O    100.00%
LYS33-Main-N     SER30-Main-O    100.00%
```

I want to get the number before "-Main" or "-Side",the result like this:

```
62 59
64 60
66 61
33 30
```

And I wrote some codes,but the result only show the number berore "-Main".

```
f1 = open(filename1)
for line in f1.readlines():
    N=re.compile(r'(\d+)-Main|-Side')
    n=N.findall(line)
    print (n)
```

The result is shown below:

```
['62', '59']
['', '60']
['66', '61']
['33', '30']
```

please someone give me some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JosephSible has mentioned, you should group the patterns in your alternation since alternation has a low precedence, but in this case you should use a non-capturing group for `-Main` and `-Side` since you don't actually want them in your output:

```
N=re.compile(r'(\d+)(?:-Main|-Side)')
```

Alternatively, you can use a lookahead pattern so you don't need any capturing group:

```
N=re.compile(r'\d+(?=-Main|-Side)')
```

Answer (score 2):

Or this as full code:

```
import re
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
   for i in f:
      print(' '.join(re.findall('\d{2}',i)[:-2]))
```

Output:

```
62 59
64 60
66 61
33 30
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/oFEBvM/1)

Comment: This incorrectly assumes that there are always another two double digits after the first two double digits, which may not be the case, especially since the third column is apparently a percentage number, which can potentially dip into single digits such as `9.87%`.

Comment: This would also fail if there are double digits in the code after the second dash, as shown in single digit in the `OG1` code, which can very likely contain double digits in some cases.

Comment: @blhsing Well, than yours :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a precedence issue. Alternation happens late enough that your regex was being parsed as "numbers followed by -Main" or "-Side". Use this regex instead: `(\d+)(-Main|-Side)`